# Can I add special button to android default keyboard

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I know that there is done button that appear in keyboard , but I want to put button on my keyboard and name it save , so the user can use it to save the record which he is entering now 
if there is another suggestion to do that , please don't hesitate to say it :)

Note : I have some multi line text-boxs so I cannot use done button.

Comment: Interesting question, but I'm guessing the solution is more complicated than anyone would hope for.

Answer (score -1):

Put a Button in your layout to save it. It is much easier. Put this line in your xml below the record fields like in a registration page :-

```
<Button id=@+id/save
layout_width="wrap_content"
layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

In your main activity, on this Button listener, write the code which you were supposed to write on the save button for keyboard.

You cannot customize Android default keyboard.
However for the last `EditText` to be filled, you can specify an action such as Done:-

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

You can fire a listener for that which is called `onEditorAction` :-

```
lastEditText.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {        
@Override
public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if(actionId==EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE){
        //do something
    }
return false;
}
```

});

Comment: Can the user also post the reason for downvoting ? I hope it is not for spelling mistake becaue that is a silly reason

Comment: You didn't answer the users question is why I down-voted.  While you supplied a viable alternative, it doesn't answer the specific question (can you add a custom button to keyboard). Peace.

Comment: Viable alternative which is good, and i also posted how to do it without using a button. using imeOptions. I also told that you cannot customize android keyboard. Please do read the answer